# min_scale and max_scale in the model config of Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

In the [Tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config) have the model config files for training, this config file has `min_scale` and `max_scale` for detection object that are set to 0.2 and 0.95 respectively by default,
I have some question about these parameters:

- These params are for detecting the size of objects?
- If we set the input size of network=300x300 and min_scale=0.2, then the network is not able to detect the objects that have size smaller than 300x0.2 = 60 pixels?
- As far as you know, the ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco has the problem for detecting the small objects, If we set the min_scale = 0.05 and train the network on small objects with the same model, Is it possible to detect small objects with size 300x0.05 = 15 pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These params are for detecting the size of objects?

Well, yes and no. Those parameters are inside the `ssd_anchor_generator` definition, which is itself an `anchor_generator`. That part of the system takes care of providing some anchor boxes for the further box prediction.

> If we set the input size of network=300x300 and min_scale=0.2, then the network is not able to detect the objects that have size smaller than 300x0.2 = 60 pixels?

No. The size of a detectable object is not just related to the `min_scale` (which only affects anchor generation), but instead is affected by, for example, data the network was trained on, network depth, etc.

> As far as you know, the ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco has the problem for detecting the small objects, If we set the min_scale = 0.05 and train the network on small objects with the same model, Is it possible to detect small objects with size 300x0.05 = 15 pixels?

Maybe? That depends entirely on your data. Modifying the `min_scale` parameter might help (and indeed it might make sense to select another range for those parameters), but experimentation with your data is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. suppose I have small objects in the training dataset and I want to check two scenarios with same model: train with min_scale = 0.2 and train with min_scale= 0.02, then what's different between two training state and final result?